# How to find files with regex and list them?

Tags: regex, command-line

I am new to the whole command-line thing and trying to figure out how to search the current directory and its sub directories for files with a specific filename via regex. Then I want to have the files listed in my command-line.

The regex should match files like:

```
B2ctes_UCUAAwF-K-large-123x322-132x423.jpg
this_is-a-123-file_name-3124x2445-4235x32.jpeg
file-32x32-64x64.png
```

The important part is the `-[number]x[number]-[number]x[number]`

My attempt looks like this:

```
find . -type f -regex ".+?-\d+x\d+-\d+x\d+\.\w{3,4}" -ls;
```

There are two problems with this:

1. `-ls` puts shows a lot of information. I just want the filenames.
2. The regex doesn’t work. I have tried to use `.+`, but even that does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `find` with `regex`:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex ".*-[[:digit:]]+x[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+x[[:digit:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]{3,4}"
```

Or on OSX:

```
find -E . -type f -regex ".*-[[:digit:]]+x[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+x[[:digit:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]{3,4}"
```

And **without regex**:

```
find . -type f -name "*-[[:digit:]]*x[[:digit:]]*-[[:digit:]]*x[[:digit:]]*.[[:alnum:]]*"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first one on linux via ssh and the second one locally on my OS X machine. Both work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply :

```
find . -type f -name '-[0-9]*x[0-9]*-[0-9]*x-[0-9]*'
```

or

```
find . -type f  -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*-[0-9]+x[0-9]+-[0-9]+x-[0-9]+.*'
```

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was not asked good enough. The filename part is variable. It could be something like "B2ctes_UCUAAwF-K-large" too. The extension could be .gif, .jpg, .jpeg or .png and the numbers are always numbers, but are variable in length. I’ll rephrase my question.

Comment: They still don’t work. I do not know why … maybe the posix-type is not supported for me?!